# Changing label text in custom UIView on the fly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom view called TimeTooltipView.  Here is the code:

TimeTooltipView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TimeTooltipView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;

-(void)configureView;

@end
```

TimeTooltipView.m

```
#import "TimeTooltipView.h"

@implementation TimeTooltipView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimeTooltipView" owner:self options:nil];
        UIView *mainView = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
        [self addSubview:mainView];

        [self configureView];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)configureView {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

@end
```

I add a TimeTooltipView in a view controller, like so:

```
TimeTooltipView *timeTooltipView = [[TimeTooltipView alloc] 

initWithFrame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 50, 50)];
timeTooltipView.timeLabel.text = @"TEST";
[self.view addSubview:timeTooltipView];
timeTooltipView.timeLabel.text = @"TEST2";
```

I need to change timeLabel's text on the fly from the view controller.  Using the code above, the view gets added and has a green background color.  But the label text never changes to "TEST" or "TEST2".

How can I change the custom view's label text on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    NSArray *subviewArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TimeTooltipView" owner:self options:nil];
        //Instead of making it subView just replace it.
        self = [subviewArray objectAtIndex:0];
        self.frame = frame;
        [self configureView];

    return self;
}

-(void)configureView {
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}
```